# Find the hidden message in the Tetris grid

Tags: word, cipher, visual

What is the message hidden within this Tetris grid?

[image: Tetris grid]

Hint 1:

> The answer is 12 letters long

Additional hints may be added if this remains unsolved.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you

> divide the playing field up into 2x3 blocks

then

> read the blocks as Braille

then you get

> CSOW / OMSU / RIAS, which anagrams to **MOSCOW RUSSIA**.

Comment: You beat me to it! One other thing worth noting is that rot13(nppbeqvat gb Jvxvcrqvn ng yrnfg, Zbfpbj jnf sbhaqrq va gur lrne 1147, rkcynvavat gur fpber ng gur gbc bs gur vzntr).

Comment: Correct. That was quick!

Comment: Also, of course, rot13(Grgevf jnf vairagrq va Ehffvn. Abg fher vs vg jnf va Zbfpbj gubhtu...).